# Doing a WHERE a='x' OR WHERE b='y' in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am starting with MongoDB and specially with MongoDB and the PHP interface to use it. I'm coming from MySQL and I'm a bit lost.

What I'm trying to do is, having a Mongo "entry" with: `username`, `password`, `email` and `country` I want to do a search to look for:

`username IS to A OR email IS to B`

How this can be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently started doing this as well; here are a few links which I've found extremely useful:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('yourCollection');
$cursor = $collection -> find(array('$or'=>array(array("username"=>"a", "email"=>"b"))));
foreach($cursor as $key){
    print_r($key);
}
```

This should get you started with working through mongo and php.  Below is a link to the translations between the two .

[Mongo to SQL Translations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php)

Lastly this is an excellent tutorial for starting:

[Learn Mongo -> Interactive Tutorial](http://www.mongly.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want $or: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or. Should look something like this:

```
db.people.find({$or: [{username:'A'}, {email:'B'}]})
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php):

```
//SELECT * FROM users WHERE a=1 or b=2
$db->users->find(array('$or' => array(array("a" => 1), array("b" => 2))));
```